# Hide first element of Dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I am using to hide first element of Dropdown, but doing so, First element is removed but the 2nd element is selected automatically,
I want that User should select elemeent manually,
Please tell how I can do this,
Currently I am doing so with Jquery:

```
$("#casue").click(function(){
        $("#casue option[value='0']").remove();
    });
```

In this way an element is removed from the list,
But I want a thing as in Gmail SignUp Form, Birthday and Gender Dropdowns,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I do that:

```
<select>
   <option value='0' hidden>Choose one</option>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
   <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yJu8b/)

Answer (score 0):

No need of jQuery, just empty the text and the first value of first option.
 [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E8CT2/)

```
<select>
   <option value=''></option>
   <option value='item1'>item1</option>
   <option value='item2'>item2</option>
   <option value='item3'>item3</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to do it by jQuery:
 **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E8CT2/1/)**

```
$('#selectBox option:first').before('<option value="" selected></option>');
```